# Can a Sukkah have all-glass walls?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, see-sight-vision-blind

Would a Sukkah that has walls that are completely transparent be kosher for use?

Comment: Why should they not?

Comment: @shmuel would you live in a transparent house?

Comment: Assuming I don't do anything private there, why not?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill It's a question. I doubt it would be so obvious to most people...

Comment: If the transparent walls are silica based, stones would become  muktza throughout the entire sukkos ;)

Comment: why is silica based material muktza?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The first mishna of [Maseches Sukkah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.2a?lang=bi) lists the different factors that would invalidate a sukkah, but transparency isn't an issue. You can also make the walls with 4 horizontal strings, each within 3 tefachim from the other one. Though if it was *completely* transparent, i.e. invisible, perhaps there would be an issue that no one could tell they're in a sukkah.

Comment: I think vertical strings are kosher too, right

Answer (score 8):

In Maseches [Sukkah 4b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.4b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) (copied below), Rava rejects Abaye's proposal for a platform without walls because there is a requirement that they be "ניכר". Therefore there may be a basis for transparent walls being invalid.

> היתה גבוהה מעשרים אמה ובנה בה עמוד שהוא גבוה עשרה טפחים ויש בו הכשר סוכה סבר אביי 
>   למימר גוד אסיק מחיצתא א"ל רבא בעינן מחיצות הניכרות וליכא‏

Comment: Ely, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for finding this interesting source! You could make your answer even more valuable by adding a translation of the gemara passage you quote. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Yoshia ([Sukkah 7b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.7b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) claims that walls must also provide shade and therefore may not be constructed from transparent material.

But I think you can decorate the walls enough to guarantee enough shade for comfort or lay plastic sheets like tarp.  Since I am a female, I am not a posek, but just suggesting my idea to help solve the problem of a sukkah with transparent walls.

Comment: Hello Harsimrat Kaur and welcome to Mi.Yodeya! Thank you for your sourced answer. Are you sure the shade referred to couldn't be the kind that glass provides?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the phrase "Since I am a female, I am not a posek" in this answer.

Comment: Yes, this site explicitly [does not provide psak](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Being or not being a posek has no relevance. If you need a psak, consult your local Orthodox rabbi. If you are the local Orthodox rabbi and want to pasken, please post it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The Pri Megadim is מסופק about this case.

Comment: Can you give the location?

Comment: Based on what potential disqualification?

Comment: You are misremembering. The PM refers to the shach.